# Spark, NegativeArraySizeException when sequencefile

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

The spark I'm using is 2.3.

I have this code snippet which reads sequence files under 'hdfspath'(there're about 20 files under this path, and each file is about 60MB),

```
SparkSession spark = ...;
JavaSparkContext jsc = JavaSparkContext.fromSparkContext(spark.sparkContext());
JavaPairRDD<BytesWritable, BytesWritable> temp = jsc.sequenceFile(hdfspath, BytesWritable.class, BytesWritable.class);
temp.take(1);
```

And it gives me this error,

```
19/04/03 14:50:18 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
19/04/03 14:50:18 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
19/04/03 14:50:18 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
19/04/03 14:50:18 INFO CodecPool: Got brand-new decompressor [.gz]
19/04/03 14:50:18 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.setCapacity(BytesWritable.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.setSize(BytesWritable.java:123)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.readFields(BytesWritable.java:179)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:71)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization$WritableDeserializer.deserialize(WritableSerialization.java:42)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.deserializeKey(SequenceFile.java:2606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.next(SequenceFile.java:2597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileRecordReader.next(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.getNext(HadoopRDD.scala:277)
```

The hdfs files I'm trying to read is the output of an old mapreduce job with output setting like this,

```
job.setOutputKeyClass(BytesWritable.class);
job.setOutputValueClass(BytesWritable.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat.class);
SequenceFileAsBinaryOutputFormat.setOutputCompressionType(job, CompressionType.BLOCK);
```

I looked into org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable.setCapacity(...) method,

```
public void setSize(int size) {
if (size > getCapacity()) {
  setCapacity(size * 3 / 2);
}
this.size = size;
}
```

Somehow the size parameter is 808464432, and causes overflow when doing size*3, which eventually causes NegativeArraySizeException.

Can anyone help to explain how come this happens, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out. Use `JavaSparkContext#newAPIHadoopFile` instead of `JavaSparkContext#sequenceFile`.